# how to change the reading channel?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, hardware, pigpio

this code is reading from channel 0, how can i change the reading channel 
MCP3008

```
adc = pi.spi_open(1, 40000, 0) # Open SPI channel 1.

 while True:

 try:

  c, d = pi.spi_xfer(adc, [1, 0x80, 0]) # Read channel 0.

  v = ((d[1]<<8) | d[2]) & 0x3FF

  micros = map(v, MIN_POT_CAP, MAX_POT_CAP, MIN_SERVO, MAX_SERVO)

  pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(SERVO, micros)
```

Comment: While it is not an issue wrt the question, something to consider for future coding: per [PEP0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) *Use 4 spaces per indentation level.* Your code will not run but throw an IndentationError at *try:*

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
c, d = pi.spi_xfer(adc, [1, 0x80, 0]) # Read channel 0.
```

to

```py
c, d = pi.spi_xfer(adc, [1, (8+ch)<<4, 0]) # Read channel ch.
```